# How to allow access to a folder?

Tags: vb.net

Trying to write text from a text box to a file, keeping any text that is already in there, but this message comes up:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Access to the path 'C:\Tickets.txt' is denied.

This is for a school assignment to create an IT ticketing software for a school.

What I have done so far:

```
Private Sub BtnComSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnComSubmit.Click
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Tickets.txt", TxtComList.Text, True)
End Sub
```

How could I give the necessary permission(s) to perform this action?

Comment: Show your code of what you have done and what is not working, then we can help you.

Comment: The user running your process does not access to the file. Hint: Try having it somewhere else than the root of the drive (ex: c:\folder\Tickets.txt)

Comment: Non-elevated applications do not have permission to write directly to the C:\ directory. Change your code so it saves to the user's Documents folder or Desktop folder instead. Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(...)` and `Path.Combine`.

Comment: @Dai I'm sorry I'm very new to code haha. How would I set that out?

Comment: @ESG Yep, I've tried that too, but have the same problem

Comment: @Codexer Edited!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Tickets.txt", TxtComList.Text, True)
```

To this:

```
Dim desktopPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop )
Dim filePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine( desktopPath , "Tickets.txt" )
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText( filePath , TxtComList.Text, True )
```

BTW, I recommend avoiding the VB-specific `My.Computer...` stuff and using the `System.IO` API so you can graduate over to C# eventually with greater familiarity with .NET's APIs. Very few people stick with VB.NET for long.

Comment: When this happens, I get the message: System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "Tickets.txt" to type 'Integer' is not valid.' FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. @Dai

Comment: @lili Please post your version of my code in your original question so we can review it, because that shouldn't happen. None of the `Path.Combine()` method overloads accept an `Int32`(`Integer` in VB) parameter argument. I suspect you have a typo somewhere.